# CouchDB from Erlang (possibly embedded)?

Tags: erlang, nosql, couchdb

TL;DR

Is it possible to access CouchDB 'directly' from Erlang, meaning use function calls from within Erlang?  Furthermore, I'd like this not to be so much a 'wrapper' around the generic REST api, but a bona-fide 'direct linkage' if possible.  In other words, I'd like to either have CouchDB 'embedded' in an Erlang app I'm writing, or perhaps the opposite ('embed' my app in CouchDB).  In other words, I'd like to use CouchDB from within Erlang much as one can use Mnesia or anything else (just access a module or modules, fire up an Erlang application, whatever).

EDIT: CouchDB and my application in same Erlang VM, if possible.

LONGER VERSION

I am currently in the (long, headache-inducing) process of evaluating a bunch of so-called 'no-sql' databases.  I need to use such a database from Erlang, but as with most everything else Erlang, it's been a joke.  I'll find a database that seems to fit my needs, then find out the only driver available is a 'joke' driver that someone posted on github which is old, not officially-supported, experimental, etc.  Then I go back to the drawing board, only to stumble again.  Most recently, I evaluated MongoDB and liked what I saw.  Alas, the driver was some github-posted thing, and it failed to compile due to syntax errors.  I 'hacked' the code to eliminate the syntax errors, but really had no idea what those faulty parts of the code did, therefore strongly suspect I didn't fix it to do what the developer intended (thus I'm sure I introduced bugs or logical errors).  Thus, again, back to the drawing board.

The main problem is that Erlang isn't Python or Ruby or [insert other popular 'hot' language], thus it just isn't well-supported once you delve into anything that wasn't included within Erlang.  This is forever a pain.

A few more notes:

Riak doesn't seem to do what I want (it has some 'eventual consistency' model where as I need something resembling ACID or transactions, at least partially, and at least for some things).

I did stumble upon some 'Hovercraft' thingy for CouchDB but wasn't able to ascertain if it does what I'm asking for in this post.

Mnesia is limited to 4GB tables or whatever, so that's out.

I'm really just trying to get a quick 'go/no-go' answer on whether to evaluate CouchDB more fully, or go back to the drawing board again.

You are also welcome to recommend whatever solution (i.e. database) you think fits with what I'm asking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is a CouchDB plugin ([sample plugin](https://github.com/janl/my-first-couchdb-plugin) + [brief plugin video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saNjXpE1h1Y))

Basically, you can write an Erlang application that's loaded directly in with CouchDB, so you have access to all the internals. Unfortunately, it's not well documented *yet*. However, this is the next major thing they are working on making really easy, so if you direct questions to the [mailing list](http://couchdb.apache.org/#mailing-lists), (dev is probably your best bet) you'll likely get lots of help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. There is [hovercraft](https://github.com/jchris/hovercraft), but you might have to update it to match modern API. CouchDB's Erlang API is not something that guaranteed to be stable *for now* since primary communication interface is the REST API.

If you need something more, you may take a look on [RCouch](https://github.com/refuge/rcouch) fork. This is static distribution of a bit enhanced CouchDB that uses rebar and could be embedded much more easily than original project.